# "Unexpected token export" in Angular app with SystemJS and TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, systemjs

### Problem: mysterious "Unexpected token export"

I happened to get this error in an Angular example running in plunker where SystemJS transpiles TypeScript code in the browser.

There was nothing wrong with the code which **ran fine locally**.

Answer (score 4):

#### Solution

This isn't an Angular problem. It's a problem with transpiling certain kinds of TypeScript files in the browser.

In my case, I tracked the problem down to a single file that **only exported an *abstract class***.

```
// Class used as a "narrowing" interface that exposes a minimal logger
// Other members of the actual implementation are invisible
export abstract class MinimalLogger {
  logs: string[];
  logInfo: (msg: string) => void;
}
```

The problem is that this file doesn't export *anything* other than the abstract class.

When I add an inert export of anything concrete ... like this:

```
export const _ = 0; // hack: must export something "real"
```

... the error goes away.

I've seen a similar problem with a file that only exports TypeScript interfaces. You have to give it at least one thing that is "real".

Environment:

- typescript@2.2.1
- systemjs@0.19.39

SystemJS Config for this example:

```
 System.config({
    // DEMO ONLY! REAL CODE SHOULD NOT TRANSPILE IN THE BROWSER
    transpiler: 'ts',
    typescriptOptions: {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    meta: {
      'typescript': {
        "exports": "ts"
      }
    },
    ...
  })
```

Comment: Just letting you know i had this exact same issue (export from file with single abstract class using systemjs and Typscript) and it was driving me crazy. Thanks